# How to call variable from one function in another file inside a function in another file?

Tags: python, function, variables

I can't really copy over all of the code in both of these files since it is over 1000 lines, but essentially I am making a program that has the variables 'strength', 'endurance', 'strength', 'dexterity', 'intelligence', 'wisdom', and 'luck' (it's an rpg game) and I am trying to get the variable 'damage', which is an equation of 'strength' * 'dexterity' / 100, into another file. All of these variables are within the function character() in a file specifically for creating your character, and I'm trying to call over these variables again in another file for the main game, inside a variable called fight(). I've tried a multitude of things such as global variables, and using return, but nothing has worked for me. I'm sorry if I explained that poorly, comment if you have any questions.

The code in question.

character.py

```
def character():
    #tons of stuff go here
    global damage
    damage = strength * dexterity / 100
```

game.py

```
def fight():
    choice = input('(Type in the corresponding number to choose.) ')
    global enemy_health
    global damage
    if choice == 1:
        print ' '
        print enemy_health,
        enemy_health += -damage
        print '-->', enemy_health
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Realised I put 'strength' twice, meant to put vitality for one of them.

Comment: I would make classes if i were you, make a character into a class

Comment: The problem is that global variables in Python aren't actually 'global', they are "global to the module". So, in `game.py` I'm assuming you've imported as such:  `import character` To access the "global" `damage` from `character`, use `character.damage`. Honestly, this *screams* poor design. As someone has suggested, you should likely use classes, or at least `dicts` or something to contain the data you need to access. Using global variables like this is not how you would go about this, and this is why RPGs as a beginning programing project are usually a bad idea. Start smaller.

Comment: So, in short, this is a textbook example of global variables leading to hard to reason about and maintain code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try importing character.py to game.py.

game.py: (edited)

```
import character
character_health = character.health
character_strength = character.strength

def fight():
...
```

But yeah, use classes.

Edit: example class

game.py:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, health, strength):
        self.health = health
        self.strength = strength
        self.alive = True

    def check_dead(self):
        self.alive = not(self.health)

    def fight(self, enemy):
        self.health -= enemy.strength
        enemy.health -= self.strength

        self.check_dead()
        enemy.check_dead()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Character(300, 10) # health = 300, strength = 10
    enemy = Character(50, 5) # health = 50, strength = 5

    player.fight(enemy)
    print("Player's health: {}\nIs he alive? {}\nEnemy's health: {}\nIs he alive? {}".format(player.health, player.alive, enemy.health, enemy.alive))
```

Comment: I would *not* use this. This obliterates namespaces. Just `import character` and use `character.health` etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, I probably shouldn't import stats like health and strength like that.